# String stays in memory VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

Lets say I use Webclient do download a string from a web page.
Why does the address stay in memory? Isn't there a way to remove it?

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem. You can't keep a URL secret. If someone uses a proxy like Fiddler they can see what URL the request is being made to, also when using HTTPS, or they can even serve a custom response to your application. Please explain the actual problem you're trying to solve, because _"Hide the URL in my application's memory"_ is obviously not the right solution to that problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the address stay in memory?

How do you know that? It stays in memory as long as you still have a reference to it – because it *must* stay in memory that long.

What happens after you no longer hold a reference is not relevant for you: the system takes care of it.

> Isn't there a way to remove it?

It will be removed once the program needs more free memory. There is almost never a reason to explicitly remove it before that point. This is known as [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Well my reason would be a webaddress which does the login and downloads module to ne self-injected. I don't want people to be able to crack my program by finding that URL, with cheatengine.

Comment: @user3264418 That’s essentially not preventable. You can store the address in memory using a [`SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be disposed explicitly, but that will only gain you so much. At some point, the address will be in memory unencrypted. This is a fundamental problem: if it were solvable, why would Cheat Engine even exist? Don’t you think other programs would also use it?